# React-router how to load nested children within children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a nested route where the navbar will load components within `<Content>`.

What I am trying to achieve is

- User clicks on `Events` from `Navbar`
- `Events` component render within `<Content>` found in `Layout.js`
- `Events` component contains a list of `EventItems`
- Clicked one of the `EventItems`
- `EventItemsOverview` component is rendered within `<Content>` ONLY.

The current issue is when an item is clicked instead of rendering `EventsItemOverview` component only, it renders it below `Events`. Two components (`Events` & `EventsItemOverview`). How do I render only 1 component at a time in `<Content>` depending on url path?

Current output loads component below Events
[image: Current output]

Expected output: when an event is clicked `EventItemOverview` should render only. Image below is correct but heading should say `EventItemOverview`. Link events/id123
[image: Expected output]

Root.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/events" component={Events} />
          <Redirect from="/" to="/home" exact />
          <Route component={Notfound} />
        </Switch>
      </Layout>
    </Router>
  );
```

Layout.js

```
return (
  <Layout>
    <MenuNav />
    <Layout>
      <Content>
        {props.children}
      </Content>
    </Layout>
  </Layout>
);
```

Events.js

```
return (
 <Fragment>
   <Row type="flex" justify="center">
     <Col>
       <Row type="flex" gutter={12} justify="center">
         {data.events.map(event => (
           <Col>
             <EventItem data={event} />
           </Col>
         ))}
       </Row>
     </Col>
   </Row>
   <Row type="flex" justify="end" align="bottom">
     <Col>
       <Pages />
     </Col>
   </Row>
     
   <Route
     exact
     path={`/events/:eventId`}
     component={(props) => <EventItemOverview {...props} data={data} />}
   />
 </Fragment>  
);
```

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand where the problem lies. The router display two event items ? I think you should provide a jsfiddle or equivalent in order to help us help you :)

Comment: Events and EventItems are two different components rendered within <Content> found within Layout.js. I am trying to only load EventItem when user clicks an event from list within Event. Please see image provided

Comment: Ok, I understand most of that with the code you provide. What I don't understand is why you are having 2 components rendered in Content. You are using react router switch, that render only one component at a time. Could you at least provide Event.js ? The map you are talking about ? (I don't think you need render on the route here but I can't be sure)

Comment: I have updated my answer. Sorry I am still new to react-router as I am trying to understand how load the single component depending on the url path within <Content>. I do not mean to load two components but simply want to load one

Comment: Ok, your explanation is really hard to understand. Let me wrap what I understand. You have `Events` component with nested `EventsItems`(number depending on `data.events` props). When clicked on `EventsItems`, it should render only `EventItemOverview`, without having as parent `Events` component. So if url `events/` it should go `Events`, if `events/23` to `EventItemOverview`. Is it correct?

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev Yes that is correct. sorry for my bad explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok you need route in `App` to handle that.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/events" component={Events} />
          <Route exact path="/events/:id" component={EventItemOverview} />
          <Redirect from="/" to="/home" exact />
          <Route component={Notfound} />
        </Switch>
      </Layout>
    </Router>
  );
```

Also remove `Route` from `Events`.

Comment: I have tried this before and it still loads the component below Events :( and when I remove Route from Events. The URL updates however the component is not rendered

Comment: Remove `Route` from `Events` and add `exact` to routes in `App`

Comment: Ah right so I just need to add exact on my Events route. Since I was passing props to my Route on Event level. How can I pass props from my root?

Comment: How were you passing them to `Events`?

Comment: Events contained the dummy data so I just called on that data. Assuming I need to move it higher up and create a provider?

Comment: You probably will use `Redux`, `Mobx`, `Context API` or smth else. And you need to pass data to `Events` and `EventItemOverview` each. Using `render` in `Route`, I don't like it. So maybe for now just copy & paste to `EventItemOverview`. And then you will do that _correctly_

Answer (score 0):

> The current issue is when an item is clicked instead of rendering
> `EventsItemOverview` component only, it renders it below `Events`. Two
> components (`Events` & `EventsItemOverview`). How do I render only 1
> component at a time in `<Content>` depending on url path?

The `Events` component is rendering a descendent route that also renders the `EventItemOverview` component. The `Events` component UI will *always* render when the path is `"/events"`, and then additionally `EventItemOverview` will be rendered below when the path matches `"/events/:eventId"`.

You have a couple options:

1. Move the descendent `path="/events/:eventId"` route out to the main `Switch` so the `Switch` can ***exclusively*** match and render either `Events` or `EventItemOverview` routes.

   ```
   function App() {
     return (
       <Router>
         <Layout>
           <Switch>
             <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
             <Route
               path="/events/:eventId"
               render={(props) => (
                 <EventItemOverview {...props} data={data} />
               )}
             />
             <Route
               path="/events"
               render={(props) => <Events {...props} data={data} />}
             />
             <Redirect from="/" to="/home" exact />
             <Route component={Notfound} />
           </Switch>
         </Layout>
       </Router>
     );
   }
   ```

   Events.js

   ```
   return (
     <Fragment>
       <Row type="flex" justify="center">
         <Col>
           <Row type="flex" gutter={12} justify="center">
             { data.events.map(event => (
               <Col>
                 <EventItem data={event} />
               </Col>
             ))}
           </Row>
         </Col>
       </Row>
       <Row type="flex" justify="end" align="bottom">
         <Col>
           <Pages />
         </Col>
       </Row>
     </Fragment>
   );
   ```
2. Render the `Events` content also on a descendent route. `Events` will now also render a `Switch` that can ***exclusively*** match and render `"/events/*"` sub-routes.

   ```
   function App() {
     return (
       <Router>
         <Layout>
           <Switch>
             <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
             <Route path="/events" component={Events} />
             <Redirect from="/" to="/home" exact />
             <Route component={Notfound} />
           </Switch>
         </Layout>
       </Router>
     );
   }
   ```

   ```
   const { path } = useRouteMatch();

   ...

   return (
     <Switch>
       <Route
         path={`${path}/:eventId`} // <-- "/events/:eventId"
         render={(props) => (
           <EventItemOverview {...props} data={data} />
         )}
       />
       <Route path={path}>         // <-- "/events"
         <Row type="flex" justify="center">
           <Col>
             <Row type="flex" gutter={12} justify="center">
               {data.events.map(event => (
                 <Col>
                   <EventItem data={event} />
                 </Col>
               ))}
             </Row>
           </Col>
         </Row>
         <Row type="flex" justify="end" align="bottom">
           <Col>
             <Pages />
           </Col>
         </Row>
       </Route>
     </Switch>
   );
   ```